# Can I customise git autocomplete?

Tags: git, autocomplete

I want to write `git chec`, hit tab and have git autocomplete actually autocomplete it to `git checkout`. Now when I do this I get a list of options, and I have to hit tab four times to get to `git checkout`, which basically takes more time than to just write the whole thing manually.

Is it possible to tell git autocomplete to just always autocomplete certain input to certain commands?

Note: I am 99% sure it autocompleted to `git checkout` when I did this on my old mac. Does git autocomplete use machine learning to evolve? Or is my muscle memory just wrong?

Comment: What "shell" do you use? Bash/zsh/fish/etc?

Comment: Autocompletion is driven by your shell. However, the autocomplete code that comes with Git is designed to work with both bash and zsh. This is all simple shell script code itself (well, rather complicated shell script code) so you can just copy it somewhere and edit it to do whatever you want.

Comment: @evolutionxbox zsh (I should've included that in the question)

Comment: @torek thanks for the tip! (even though is sounds a bit complicated)

Comment: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions

Comment: @evolutionxbox I actually tried that plugin, but the autosuggestion also includes the last branch I checked out so not exactly what I am looking for. Do you know if it's possible to just choose the fist word in the suggestion?